# If $p=4k+3$ then $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[\sqrt{-1}]$ is a field

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to know about an elementary proof (at the level of elementary number theory) 
of the fact

If $p$ is a prime number of the form $4k+3$ then $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[\sqrt{-1}]$ is a field where
$$
\mathbb{Z}_{p}[\sqrt{-1}]:=\{a+b\sqrt{-1} : a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{p}\}
$$
and the addition and the multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[\sqrt{-1}]$ are the "obvious" operations.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\mathbb Z_p[\sqrt{-1}]$?

Comment: The problem with that is that there is nothing called $\sqrt{-1}$ in your context, and there are no obvious operations to talk about. One way of making sense of your question is to interpret $\mathbb Z_p[\sqrt{-1}]$ as the quotient ring  $\mathbb Z_p[X]/(X^2+1)$.

Comment: Thanks @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez for the answer. I denote $\sqrt{-1}$ to $\imath$ (the imaginary unit) and $(a+b\imath)+(c+d\imath) = (a\overline{+}b)+(b\overline{+}d)\imath$, $(a+b\imath).(c+d\imath)=
(-b\overline{{\cdot}}d \overline{+} a\overline{\cdot}c)+(a\overline{{\cdot}}d\overline{+}b\overline{{\cdot}}c)\imath$, with $\overline{+}$ and $\overline{{\cdot}}$ the addition and the multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, respectively.

I was searching for an answer that does not use (directly) "R is a field iff the ideal $(X^2+1)$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]$"

Comment: Well, I guess you mean that you denote $i$ one of the two elements of $\mathbb C$ such that $i^2=-1$, but then $\mathbb Z_p[i]$ does not mean anything.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is (in my rewording)

> for what primes $p$ is the quotient ring $R=\mathbb Z_p[X]/(X^2+1)$ a field?

$R$ is a field iff the ideal $(X^2+1)$ is prime ---because the ring $\mathbb Z_p[X]$ is a principal ideal domain— and this happens iff the element $X^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_p[X]$. Since the polynomial is quadratic, it is irreducible iff it has no roots in the field $\mathbb Z_p$, which happens iff $-1$ is not a square in $\mathbb Z_p$.

So your question is equivalent to

> for what primes is $-1$ a square in $\mathbb Z_p$.

Hopefully you know the answer to this.